# Convert Buffer (image) to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, apollo

I'm looking for the best way to send image files to my server using Apollo Express, and Node.
Getting the information there doesn't seem to be an issue, I convert the object into a string but can't find out how to convert it back to a regular file object to store away.

What I have so far;

```
JS - let buffer = await toBase64(file);
```

Through Apollo server..

```
Node - let buffer = Buffer.from(args.image, 'base64');
```

This gives me a Buffer. I'm unsure how to proceed with NodeJS to convert this back to a file object.

Thanks

Comment: to store, one would use fs, like https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlewritefiledata-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the various [write or writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) methods which accept a `Buffer`.

```
const fs = require("fs");

let buffer = Buffer.from(
  "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAGCAIAAABxZ0isAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAQSURBVBhXY/iPAwygxP//AAjcj3EdtT3BAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
  "base64"
);

fs.writeFile("pic.png", buffer, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("The file has been saved!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will be helpfull for you

```
const file = new File([
      new Blob(["decoded_base64_String"])
    ], "output_file_name");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don’t think this works in node though unless I import the File constructor.